# numpy: how to extrude base array along multiple axes?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a "seed" array like this one:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> seed = np.array([[2*i, 2*i + 1] for i in range(4)])
>>> seed.shape
(4, 2)
```

I want to "extrude" this array along two additional axes to end up with a new array, let's call it `extrusion`, having shape (5, 4, 3, 2), and such that, for each valid pair of indices (*i*, *k*), the subarray (a.k.a. "slab") at `extrusion[i, :, k, :]` will be a copy of the original seed array.

> What's the numpy "best practice" for doing this sort of thing?

In the addendum below I give a couple of approaches I can think of for doing this, both exploiting numpy broadcasting to get the desired results, but I am hoping to find an alternative that is more readily understandable to those who are not familiar with numpy broadcasting.  E.g. a constructor or factory method that took a "seed" and a desired final shape, and performed the required extrusions behind the scenes.

Thanks!

Addendum: One hacky way to generate the desired extrusion would be to add together a suitably shaped array of zeros and a suitably reshaped seed array:

```
>>> shape = 5, 4, 3, 2
>>> zeros = np.zeros(shape, dtype=seed.dtype)
>>> extrusion = seed.reshape((1, 4, 1, 2)) + zeros
```

(In the shape tuple given to `seed.reshape`, the axes that get length 1 are those along which the extrusion will occur.  The lengths of the remaining axes must match those of the corresponding axes in the desired final shape.)

This approach does produce the desired result; for example, the `[1, :, 2, :]` slab of the extrusion is a replica of the seed array.

```
>>> extrusion[1, :, 2, :]
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
>>> seed
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

Slightly less hacky would be to create a receiving array having the right shape, and just assign the seed array to it (after reshaping it suitably):

```
>>> extrusion = np.empty(shape, dtype=seed.dtype)
>>> extrusion[...] = seed.reshape((1, 4, 1, 2))
>>> extrusion[3, :, 2, :]
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

Edit: thanks to wim for suggested simplifications to the `np.zeros` and `np.empty` calls.

Comment: `np.zeros(np.product(shape), dtype=seed.dtype).reshape(shape)` can be written simply `np.zeros(shape, dtype=seed.dtype)`.  Besides, I think your method is quite fine.  Isn't this exactly what the Ellipsis object is for?

Comment: You might be able to do it also with `np.tensordot` and some kind of high-dimensional identity matrix-like thing, but unless you're a mathematician it wouldn't be as readily understandable as using the broadcasting!

Comment: I reckon broadcasting is the most "numpy" way to do it - taking advantage of the language's strengths! I think your reshaping method is very slick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.broadcast_to` to broadcast your array to the desired shape:

```
extrusion = np.broadcast_to(seed.reshape(1, 4, 1, 2), (5, 4, 3, 2))
```

This works for the same reason that your assignment to `extrusion[...]` works, but by broadcasting to the given shape you can do it in a single expression.

This will produce a view of the original array, with multiple result cells being views of the same cell of the original array, so you shouldn't mutate the result unless you know *exactly* how that works. If you need a "regular" result that can be safely mutated, you can copy the broadcasting result:

```
extrusion = np.broadcast_to(seed.reshape(1, 4, 1, 2), (5, 4, 3, 2)).copy()
```